# IPv6 6rd configuration on Cisco router

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

I'm trying to setup ipv6 6rd on a cisco router and I have the following information:

```
6rd IPv6 Prefix: 2001:2002::
6rd Border Relay IPv4 Address: 217.209.228.166
6rd IPv6 prefix length: 32
6rd IPv4 Prefix length: 0 bits
```

As I understand it, I should create a tunnel interface containing the following:

```
interface Tunnel0 
 ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX ::/128 anycast
 ipv6 enable
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet8
 tunnel mode ipv6ip 6rd
 tunnel 6rd prefix 2001:2002::/32
 tunnel 6rd br 217.209.228.166
```

GigabitEthernet8 is my WAN interface and running:

```
show tunnel 6rd
```

shows a General Prefix 2001:2002:xxxx:xxxx::/64 where x represents hex notations of my assigned ip to WAN interface.

Trying to set an ipv6 address on a LAN interface with the DELEGATED_PREFIX returns an error that it is overlapping with the configured /128 address on Tunnel0.

I am at a loss here on what needs to be done to make it work correctly and any help would be appreciated!

**Update with comments on answer from Sander Steffann:**

My ISP only supplies one /64 net per customer and it has to be their 32bit prefix combined with the hex notation of my 32bit ip address they have assigned to me.

I have seen a couple of examples of configurations for consumer grade routers where they set up ipv6 using 6rd with my ISP. They only get the one /64 network but that is enough and seems to work fine.

Can I configure it another way without a tunnel interface such that I do not consume a /64 network for the tunnel?

As I understand it I have no way to get a bigger prefix, no bits I can shave of anywhere.

**Update 2:**

I've created a new vlan interface with

```
ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX ::/64 eui-64
```

and unnumbered command on tunnel interface

```
 ipv6 unnumbered Vlan10
```

I also have a default ipv6 route pointing to the tunnel interface but trying to ping ipv6 resources such as the Google public dns: 2001:4860:4860::8888 fails.

Checking the tunnel interface reveals 0 packets input and I'm unsure of how I can troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the whole IPv4 address as part of the IPv6 prefix. The 32 bits of the prefix you configured plus the 32 bits of the IPv4 address give you a /64. With a /64 you can only have one LAN, and you already configured it on the tunnel itself. That doesn't leave you any /64 prefixes for other networks.

You need to have a bigger prefix for what you want. A /63 would give you two /64s, a /62 would give four, etc. So you need to shave off some bits somewhere.

The way you are configuring 6rd it is more like 6to4. The idea ox 6rd is that you map your own IPv6 prefix to your own IPv4 prefix. Those IPv4 addresses might be private addresses. If you for example map 10.0.0.0/8 to an IPv6 /32 then you only need to map the last 24 bits of the IPv4 address. 32+24 gives you a /56 per IPv4 address. That allows you to configure 256 IPv6 networks per IPv4 address.

Comment: Updated my question with some comments on your answer.

Comment: Your ISP is giving you bad service then, because you should always get multiple IPv6 prefixes. In your case just run the tunnel unnumbered and move the IPv6 address statement to the LAN interface

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately all ISPs in Sweden seems to be refusing IPv6 to consumers except for this kind of tunnel. I have created a new vlan interface with an IPv6 address using the tunnel prefix and then used the unnumbered command on the tunnel pointing to that vlan interface. I also have a default ipv6 route pointing to the tunnel but my attempts to ping the google dns (2001:4860:4860::8888) using the vlan interface as a source fails.

Comment: OT, but I think RIPE should have a talk with Swedish ISPs, then.